# Does LINQ perform subsequent Selects in memory?

Tags: .net, linq

If I use LINQ to get some data from a database and then later on I take that data and start performing new LINQ commands on it, does it go back to the DB? Or just do it in memory? Only talking about reading data.

So if I do this:

```
var tabledata = dbContext.Table1.Where(u => u.isActive);
int count = tabledata.Count();
```

And then later on I want to quickly get a particular value so I do this:

```
string username = tabledata.Where(u => u.ID == 1).Select(u => u.Username).Single();
```

Did I just hit the DB again? Or did it perform the select on a cached copy of the table in memory?

Edit: OK, after numerous edits, what I'm trying to get at is, if we assume that I've successfully hit the DB and returned an IQueryable, will subsequent queries against that object hit the DB or stay in memory?

Comment: The first statement doesn't go to the database.

Comment: OK, that was a bad example. I added a where clause to the first statement.

Comment: read up on LINQ deferred execution ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: The first statement still didn't go to the database.

Comment: in this bit of code `var tabledata = dbContext.Table1.Where(u => u.isActive);` you haven't gone to the database ...

Comment: @Xander: OK, I looked at that article. I know the call to Count() will force it to execute. So... Now will it perform further queries against tabledata in memory?

Comment: @Legion: No.  `tabledata` is not cached, unless you've told EF to cache it.

Comment: @Legion Subsequent calls to `Count` will continue make database calls. If you call `Count`, cache the result ...

Comment: You *want* it to go back to the database with these updated queries. *They are different queries, using different data.* You do not want EF pulling the entire table into memory (unless you actually do want that, in which case, write the query that does so and then write further queries against that materialized result) (and I hope for your sake that if you do, the table is small).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tabledata = dbContext.Table1.Where(u => u.isActive);
int count = tabledata.Count();
```

executes when you call `Count()`.

```
string username = tabledata.Where(u => u.ID == 1)
                           .Select(u => u.Username)
                           .Single();
```

executes when you call `Single()`.

Whether the second call is cached in memory or not depends on whether or not you set up a caching solution.  In Linq to SQL or EF out of the box, this will make two calls to the database.

Answer (score 3):

In your posted code, you hit the DB once: when you call .Single(). The .Table1, the .Where, and the .Select are all lazily evaluated, passed into the .Single() call.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made a better example. I've updated my question to better reflect what I'm trying to understand.